# .NET DataAdapter DataTableUpdate stripps down my integer value

Tags: .net, database, datatable, firebird, dataadapter

i have a firebird database. my dataset looks like the following:

```
<xs:element name="MYTABLE">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MYKEY" type="tgKEY" msdata:AutoIncrementSeed="0" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" />
            <xs:element name="NO" type="tgM" minOccurs="0" default="-1" />
            <xs:element name="NAME" type="tgName" />
            <xs:element name="MODUL" type="xs:short" />
            <xs:element name="FUNKTION" type="xs:short" />
            <xs:element name="RECHT" type="xs:short" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

the problematic column are MODUL. In the firebird database it has the datatype smallint, which is the equivalent to xs:short. So, in .NET i will run a dataAdapter.Update to push all changes to my database from a dataTable. The column MODUL has the value 108 in it. But after the Update runs, in the database every value higher than 100 is stripped down to 10?!

i really would like to know why this is happening... i have no idea at the moment :(

kind regards and big thx for help!

edit:

DataAdapter is from type: System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter
The Firebird DataAdapter is: FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter